# How to simulate "base error rate" in art_illumina?

Tags: ngs, simulated-data

I'd like to simulate 10% sequencing error using `art_illumina`. The simulator doesn't have a parameter that I can just give the 10%, but it has this:

```
-qs  --qShift   the amount to shift every first-read quality score by
-qs2 --qShift2  the amount to shift every second-read quality score by
                NOTE: For -qs/-qs2 option, a positive number will shift up 
                quality scores (the max is 93) that reduce substitution sequencing 
                errors and a negative number will shift down quality scores that 
                increase sequencing errors. If shifting scores by x, the error
                rate will be 1/(10^(x/10)) of the default profile.
```

Heng Li's `wgsim` has an option for base error rate. Can I do the same for `art_illumina`?

**Q:** Does the "error rate" in the description mean sequencing error? If I set both `qShift` and `qShift2` to 10, `1/(10^(x/10)) == 0.1, where x is 10`, does that mean 10 is the value I should give to the simulator?

Comment: "a positive number will shift up quality scores that reduce substitution sequencing errors" -- I suspect you want to do the opposite: "a negative number will shift down quality scores that increase sequencing errors"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify an error profile to do this. However, you can shift quality scores of an existing profiles to get 10% error, which is easier than defining a complete profile.

For example, Illumina HiSeq 1000 has the error rate of 0.1% and you want 100 time more errors, so you should shift down the quality scores by 20 by setting both `qShift` and `qShift2` to -20. The following code will simulate paired end reads with 10% error.

```
art_illumina -ss HS10 -i reference.fa -qs -20 -qs2 -20 -sam -p -l 100 -f 20 -m 200 -s 10 -o output
```